# All the 3 users got downvoted for closing the answer

Tags: discussion, downvotes, etiquette, behavior

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508941/where-did-you-hear-about-us?noredirect=1) was closed by 3 users. After that, the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8333125/rajkumar-p) decided to downvote the questions/answers of all 3 of us for revenge, I guess.

What should one do in this situation?

The downvotes can be seen in the profiles of the 3 voters:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/2521680/rockwell-rice?tab=topactivity
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/2763926/artamiel?tab=topactivity
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564298/rajdeep-singh?tab=topactivity

I am fairly new to meta, so please guide me or if it's not allowed to ask these questions, I will take it down.

Comment: It's OK to ask general questions relating to suspected vote abuse on Meta. However, if you want a specific case to be investigated, then it makes more sense to raise a moderator flag, since only moderators can investigate or do anything about vote abuse. As Makoto points out, it is generally not necessarily to raise a flag at all, since there are automated processes in place that will correct this type of serial downvoting.

Comment: "Children" and Adults alike are welcome on SO; and how those children/adults use their votes is up to them at the end of the day.

Comment: Not the exact same scenario, but I think the answer still applies: wait 24 hours, then custom mod flag if it hasn't fixed itself.

Comment: P**sing off someone who (a) hasn't bothered to read the site rules (b) has such a thin skin that they try to take petty revenge with downvotes, is a badge of honour. Wear it with pride for helping to maintain the high standards of the site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing.

Let the person be upset about it if they have to be; if someone decides to go around and downvote all of their posts, then the serial voting script will correct it.  We don't have to police it any further than that.

Comment: Note that, based on what we can see on the activity of the users, it's unlikely the system will "catch" these, as they each only received 1 downvote. But then the formula is secret, so it might well notice that the votes were related.

Comment: If anyone want to know more about *serial voting*, here is the [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).